# Can FFMPEG capture from the screen in Windows?

Tags: windows, display, ffmpeg, screen-capture

I am trying to capture a certain region of the screen (actually its specifically a number of visible windows) on Windows XP with FFMPEG but I can only find options to capture from X11:

> http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC4

Is there any way to do it using the win32 binaries on Windows XP?  If it can't I am open to any hacks like making various windows X11 accessible some how?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766333/capture-windows-screen-with-ffmpeg) you can find some good answers too.

Comment: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2011/08/ffmpeg-screen-capture-directshow/ describes how basically use a directshow screen capture device. (for windows anyway).

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using FFmpeg and [**screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free**](http://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free).

Sample command

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=screen-capture-recorder -r 24000/1001 -q 1 out.avi
```

[Small writeup](http://svnpenn.github.io/2012/07/ffmpeg-screencast-windows)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on Windows 7:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop output.flv
```

See [FFmpeg gdigrab documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for the same thing. I found that ffmpeg can't capture from the Windows screen.

However, you could try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) which works on all platforms.

Comment: Note ImageMagick will capture images not video.